# CSV import from JAVA using postgres script

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, csv

So I have this script that i need to execute from  a Java web application.
The file containing this lines is located under WEB-INF

```
    truncate table amm.mm_dosage_unit;
    alter table amm.mm_dosage_unit add column code_new_version character varying(1);
    copy amm.mm_dosage_unit FROM 'code_list.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV;
```

I use reader to execute each of the lines.
Problem is that I dont know how to scpecifie the correct path for my .csv file and i get `No such file or directory` error.

Any ideas

Comment: In PostgreSQL, when you use the `COPY` command (not the `\copy` command from psql), it is looking for files on the server that runs PostgreSQL, not on the client side. Is your web application running on the same machine as PostgreSQL?

Comment: yes. it is the same machine always.

Comment: Then you need to specify the full path of the csv file, and also make sure that the hierarchy of folders and the file itself are readable by the user account that runs PostgreSQL.

Comment: Understood. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, the SQL query is running on the server, which is a separate filesystem to the client running the web application.

The sql server would be looking for a file on the server, while the CSV file is actually located on the client's machine.